# Obtain list of files from input

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

I have this input `<input type="file" id="file" name="file" accept="image/*" multiple>` this allow  the user select several images and I need to pass all of them to my `FormData` so I do this:

```
var formdata = new FormData();
var files = $('#file')[0].files[0];
formdata.append('file',files);
```

But that only take the first image from de list, How can i take all the images and store all of them in `var files`?

Thanks in advance

**EDIT:** The backend I use is `django/python` and if I use this way in my backend detect only one image from the list like this `[<InMemoryUploadedFile: img.png (image/png)>]` and using just `var files = $('#file')[0].files;` show me nothing.

Comment: `var files = $('#file')[0].files` ?

Comment: ^^^ I mean you're doing `files[0]`, so ....

Comment: Hi VelimirTchatchevsky and Taplar I edited the post to specify what happend whe i did what you suggest

Answer (score 1):

There are many problems:

1. You can't redeclare the same variable if you want to keep its previous values
2. You need to change the index so that it's not saving to the same spot
3. $("#file") - shouldn't be an array, it's an object so i'm surprised it's not throwing an error

Let's say your code is legit. You could do this:

```
var files=[];
var length = $("#file").length;
for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
   files[i] = $('#file')[i];
}
formdata.append('file',files);
```

Comment: Doing some testing I think `JQuery` was the problem, so I use pure `JavaScript`

Answer (score 0):

This was my solution

```
var formdata = new FormData();
var files=[];
var count = document.getElementById('file').files.length;
for (i = 0; i < cont; i++) {
    files[i] = document.getElementById('file').files[i];
    formdata.append('file',files[i]);
}
```

Using `JQuery` for length only brings me 1 element and gives me more problems so 
I use puere `JavaScript` for this part and works fine